# Which transaction isolation level to choose for atomic "Get Or Create" Scenario

Tags: entity-framework, transactions, entity-framework-6, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

Which Transaction IsolationLevel is the best to guarantee that only 1 Datarow get created.
Assuming SQL Server 2012 and EntityFramework 6 is used.

```
    using(var db = new XyzContext())
    {
        using(var dbContextTransaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction(???))
        {
            try
            {

                Item obj = db.Item.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Hashcode.Equals(hashCode));

//it is possible that 2 threads are coming through here and both have obj == null

                if(obj == null)
                {
                    obj = db.Item.Add(new Item
                    {
                        Hashcode = hashCode,
                        State = 0,

                    });
                }

                db.SaveChanges();

                dbContextTransaction.Commit();
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                dbContextTransaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've added more information to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your scenario was update, then *Snapshot* is good,(which is a default behavior of ef 6).

But in your case which is insert, then most of methods would not work properly.

You must be sure that your lock escalation level is table(which is default).
Then apply *RepeatableRead* transaction mode.
It prevents other threads from reading the table, until first thread is done.

It's better to have a *unique constraint* column on one of your columns instead of this method.

Or create a special table in your sql server database, then put row lock on specific record of that table before your main query & insert, then do your works, there is not bottle neck for your other operations with that table and is fast enough.

Good luck

Comment: So what you basically saying is that RepeatableRead would solve my problem if i use the transaction locking strategy and dont want to use the unique constraint?

Comment: Yes, but it does cost too much. row lock on specific table is far better than this solution. both of them are correct.

Comment: If unique constraint is possible in your scenario, then do that, it's better than all of them.

Comment: With "Row lock" you mean READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON. Right?!

Comment: Basically the default behavior of EF6

Comment: If i would use unioque constraint column an exception would be propagated if 2 threads try to write the same hashcode. This could be even more expensive.

Comment: No, row lock on specific table is not equivalent to default behavior of entity framework 6, I mean you put a lock on your database level to have thread safety, this is uncommon because lots of people don't know this method, 2. an exception of unique constraint which may not occur every time and is indexed based is far better than locking a whole table on all threads.